# How to add yaml to file.yaml in a specific place?

Tags: select, yaml, yq

I'm using `yq` and i'm struggling to figure out the below problem.

Given a `file.yaml` containing the below:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
  - cluster:
      age: 50
      server: dev
    name: apple
  - cluster:
      age: 50
      server: prod
    name: orange
```

what is the yq command i need to replace `file.yaml` with a file that adds yaml for the cluster where `name: orange` only, so that `file.yaml` looks like this afterwards:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
  - cluster:
      age: 50
      server: dev
    name: apple
  - cluster:
      age: 50
      server: prod
      extensions:
      - name: xx.io
        extension:
          subnet:
          - 1.2.3.4/32
    name: orange
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Which implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) of `yq` do you mean? In any case, `select` can pick the right object, `+=` will update.

Using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq):

```bash
yq '(.clusters[] | select(.name == "orange")).cluster += load("extension.yaml")' file.yaml
```

Using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq):

```bash
yq -y '(.clusters[] | select(.name == "orange")).cluster += input' file.yaml extension.yaml
```

Input `file.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
  - cluster:
      age: 50
      server: dev
    name: apple
  - cluster:
      age: 50
      server: prod
    name: orange
```

Input `extension.yaml`:

```yaml
extensions:
- name: xx.io
  extension:
    subnet:
    - 1.2.3.4/32
```

Output:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
  - cluster:
      age: 50
      server: dev
    name: apple
  - cluster:
      age: 50
      server: prod
      extensions:
        - name: xx.io
          extension:
            subnet:
              - 1.2.3.4/32
    name: orange
```

Comment: thank you, I was referring to the Mikefarah version of yq. is it possible to do what you did but inline, without an extension yaml file?

Comment: @gurpsone Sure, just replace `load("extension.yaml")` with the actual content, i.e. `{"extensions":[{"name":"xx.io","extension":{"subnet":["1.2.3.4/32"]}}]}`.

Comment: thanks, this works perfectly.

is it possible to delete this newly added part aswell?

i tried this:

`yq -i '(.clusters[] | select(.name == "*x-eu-xx-1*")).cluster - {"extensions":[{"name":"xx.io","extension":{"also-proxy":["104.18.114.97/32","104.18.115.97/32"]}}]}' ~/.kube/config`

`Error: maps not yet supported for subtraction`

Comment: @gurpsone I don't understand how you want to match `{"name":"xx.io"}` based on `.name == "*x-eu-xx-1*"`, but `yq 'del(.clusters[].cluster.extensions | select(.[].name == "xx.io"))'` would delete it based on literal string matching. Use [`test(regEx)`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/string-operators#test-regex) instead for matching against a RegEx.